# IndexError txt file: list index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

in my program I extract data (floating and integer) from a .txt file and apply matrix calculations on it. For the line:

```
reaction_data[kk + 1,dd]=input_[dot(kk,12) + dd + 19]
```

it returns :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and I can't see where I'm referring to an index whose data doesn't exist, it seems correct to me though. Can you help me? Thank you very much. (I use smop module so some notations are differents than numpy ex: dot(,) here =np.dot(,) with numpy)

```
inputf=open('precipitation.txt','rt')
zi=[]
for ligne in inputf.read().splitlines():
    ligne = ligne.strip()
    if ligne=="":
        continue
    nb = ligne.split()[-1]
    if '.' in nb or 'E' or 'inf' in nb:
        nb = float(nb)
    else:
        nb = int(nb)
    zi.append(nb)
input_=zi
inputf.close()

diffusion=input_[1]

D=matlabarray(cat(input_[2],input_[3],input_[4]))

k=matlabarray(cat(input_[5],input_[6],input_[7]))

v=zeros(3,3)

for kk in cat(arange(1,3)).reshape(-1):
    v[kk,1]=input_[dot((kk - 1),3) + 8]

    v[kk,2]=input_[dot((kk - 1),3) + 9]

    v[kk,3]=input_[dot((kk - 1),3) + 10]

time=input_[17]

clusterrization=input_[18]

reaction_nb=input_[19]    
reaction=matlabarray(cat(input_[20],input_[32],input_[44],input_[56],input_[68],input_[80]))

reaction_data=zeros(6,12)

cluster=matlabarray([])

for kk in cat(arange(0,5)).reshape(-1):
    for jj in cat(arange(1,12)).reshape(-1):
        reaction_data[kk + 1,jj]=input_[dot(kk,12) + jj + 19]
....
```

Comment: looks like `input_` is a list, and the stuff in [] is the index that's too big.

Comment: You speak about `cluster=matlabarray([])` ? @hpaulj I don't understand very well

Comment: Oh yes about `input_[dot(kk,12) + jj + 19]` yes but I don't see how to do it really